# Fill bootstrap column with image with same height as other text-column

Tags: html, css, image, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox

not sure if possible but I want to ask anyway:

I'm using flex to create a sticky footer.
There are bootstrap-containers for the header, content and footer.
My content-row exists of three columns: navigation, image and text.

I'd like my image to fill its column (respecting ratio, so hidden overflow) but no more than the text. In the example below I get the left situation (cause the image uses the 100% height) although I want the right one. How can I create this "empty" space?

[image: example image]

```
<body>
   <div id="header" class="container-fluid"></div>

   <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="content" class="container-fluid">
         <div class="row">
            <div class="col-5">
            </div>
            <div class="col-2">
               <div class="limit">
                  <img src="..." />
               </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
            </div>
         </div>
      </div>
   </div>

   <div id="footer" class="container-fluid"></div>
</body>
```

```
body {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  min-height: 100vh;
}
.wrapper {
  flex: 1;
}

.limit {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.limit img {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am thinking that you could try `background-size:cover` in your CSS.

This should make the height of the image 100% of its parent. It does however rely on the image being a background rather than inserted onto the page in an `<img>` manner.

It also sort of relies on the columns being always a static height but *Meh!!* That's only so the image doesn't pixelate if the column becomes taller than the image. It will still work if the column height varies. Perhaps best to make an image with a max height that you need.

Also, when specifying the image in your CSS another thing may help. `50% 50%` will make sure the image is always centered despite being not quite the right shape for the column.

**CSS**

```
.limit{
  background: url( path-to-image ) 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

At this point, the image column may not show at all because it has nothing in it and therefore no height. You can add `h-100` to the class..... *I think*.

**HTML**

```
<div class="limit h-100">
```

Comment: Thx, I added height: 100%; to the limit-class and it worked perfectly! I think this will be the easiest fix.